# Alternative solution for TextBox's SelectionChanged event?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, textbox, keypress

Because TextBox doesn't have the SelectionChanged event like RichTextBox, I'm trying to replace that event with KeyPress and MouseDown event. It worked well with MouseDown event because the event is called after Selection has changed, but not with KeyPress event.

Then I tried to use KeyUp event to solve my problem. But then I found out that if user hold down the arrow key, the KeyUp event won't be called.

Is there a way to solve this?

If you have another way to replace SelectionChanged event, you can share it too.

Comment: have you tried KeyDown?

Comment: Explain! `PreviewKeyDown``is called (repeatedly) if the user holds down an arrow key.

Comment: Did you read my question thoroughly? I want an event that occurs after the SelectionStart has changed after a key pressed.

Comment: You're right. I thought I got it working. Now I can only think of workarounds, like using a timer upon keydown or using a RTB after all.. - Or adding logic to the code to make it __know in advance whether the key will__ actually change the selection.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, maybe there is another way to solve it. You want to see which text user selected inside your event?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @TaW I tried to use endless loop with BackGroundWorker to check for Selection change, but I don't know how it will affect my PC performance. I tried to use timer too, but I think there must be a way better than this.

Adding logic to the code may cost a lot of effort to do because there are a lot of things can cause Selection to change such as Ctrl + V, character key, Shift, Backspace, Space, Ctrl + A, Ctrl + X, etc...

Comment: The timer idea was meant to run start the timer only on keydown and stop it at keyup again. Yes, there quite a few things to watch for, but add the arow keys and I'd say you pretty much have nailed it all.. - And, as usual it is well worth listening to Hans!

Comment: Nice ideal, I think the timer will work smoothly now :D How can I didnt think of stopping the timer on KeyUp event? :( - By the way, who is Hans? (I'm new to this site, and new to windows form too :D)

Comment: He is an icon on many .NET topics, especially UI, Winforms, Graphics, a little as Eric Lippert or Jon Skeet. His comment above pointed you to the XY-problem fallacy, ie the observation, that some of the hard problems are so hard because the real probelm and its solution lie somewhere else altogether.. (Q: How can I dodge a bullet? A: Don't! Prevent the bullet being fired in the first place..!)